# Executing a php code with parameters from jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need to call a php page **page1.php** with parameters through **$_POST** method from a jQuery code, without reloading the page from which I make the call, let's call it **page0.php** ..

So this is the code I wrote in **page0.php**

```
<img id="leftUp" src="/imagenes/cursor_1.png" width="52" height="52" ondragstart='return false;'/>

<div id="activity"style="text-align:left;position:relative;left:120px;">
   <h3 style="color: yellow;"></h3>
</div>

<script>

  var $level = 1;

  $("#leftUp").click(function()
  {
    var $hOffset = -5;
    var $vOffset = -5;

    $hOffset *= $level;
    $vOffset *= $level;

    $("#activity").text("Values h: " + $hOffset + " - v: " + $vOffset);

    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax(
    { 
      url: "page1.php",
      method: 'POST',
      data: new FormData(this),
      params:
      {
        interrupt: '14',
        hOffset: $hOffset,
        vOffset: $vOffset
      },
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(data)
      {
          alert('Success');
      },
      failure:function(transport)
      { 
        alert('Error');
      }
    });
  });
});

</script>
```

And the code for **page1.php** is basically this:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["interrupt"]))
{
    $interrupt = urlencode($_POST["interrupt"]);

    /* 
      write the interrupt number into the interrupt
      reference file
    */
    exec("echo '$interrupt' > $intFile"); 
}

if(isset($_POST["hOffset"]))
{
    $hOffset = urlencode($_POST["hOffset"]); 
}

if(isset($_POST["vOffset"]))
{
    $vOffset = urlencode($_POST["vOffset"]); 
}

/* other stuff here ... */

include("page0.php");
?>
```

I previously did something similar in the thread: '[Upload a file and reloading a div instead reloading a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27422820/upload-a-file-and-reloading-a-div-instead-reloading-a-page)', but my code is not working at all.

The content of the div **activity** is successfully updated, and the pop-up window of '**Success**' string is shown, but the PHP code seems to be not executed.

The problem should be into the jQuery code inside the **$.ajax** block, but I am not an experienced web programmer, so I really do not know how I can solve this.

Any suggestion is very appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:** I modified the **ajax** as follows:

```
$.ajax(
{ 
  url: "page1.php",
  type: 'GET',
  data: 
  {
    interrupt: "14",
    hOffset: $hOffset,
    vOffset: $vOffset
  },
  contentType: false,
  cache: false,
  processData: false,
  success: function(data)
  {
      alert('Success');
  },
  failure:function(transport)
  { 
    alert('Error');
  }
});
```

But still nothing happens.

Comment: I think you don't need this line: data: new FormData(this).
in page1.php you only use the specified params. And I think that new FormData(this) doesn't work, because 'this' is in this case an Image, because the click-function is on an Image with an id: leftUp -- but i am not sure

Comment: What is the error coming...can you check in your browser developer console log ...

Comment: I took it out that line from page0.php, but nothing happens. : (

Comment: **Aze K**, the browser is not reporting any error.

Comment: @simo-zz why you include("page0.php"); in page 1?

Comment: @simo-zz what you get in response ?

Answer (score 0):

you no need to

```
data:new FormData(this)
```

try this

```
 $.ajax(
    { 
      url: "page1.php",
      method: 'POST',
      data: 'interrupt=14&hOffset='+hOffset+'&vOffset='+vOffset,
success:function(response){
//do something
},
 failure:function(transport)
      { 
        //do something
      }
});
```

Comment: Same as above, it's not working. Thank you **Nahid**.